# Where does the matrix "I" come from in this formula for hyperbolic reflection?

Tags: matrix-equations, hyperbolic-geometry

In [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model#Reflections) what does `I` represent in this equation?

[image: Hyperbolic Reflection Matrix]

As an aside for clarification, does the block matrix at the end of the equation mean "a new matrix with `I` spread out in the lower right, `-1` in the top left, and `0` filling the remaining spaces on the top row and left column"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In matrix notation, particularly with no other context, $I$ almost always represents the identity matrix of the appropriate size, i.e. a diagonal matrix whose entries are all equal to 1. Likewise, if $0$ is used in reference to a matrix it is the zero matrix of corresponding size. So in this context, where $\mathbf{u}$ is an $n$-vector, and so $\mathbf{uu}^T$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, in the expression

$R = I - 2 \mathbf{uu}^T \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix}$

the first $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix, and inside the block matrix the second $I$ is the $(n - 1) \times (n - 1)$ identity, and the $0$s are suitably sized vectors of $0$s. To put it another way, the block matrix is actually just the $n \times n$ identity matrix with the first entry multiplied by $-1$.

Comment: I re-read the entire section of that article multiple times confident I was just misunderstanding something. Never considered that I just forgot a basic piece of matrix notation, huh. Thanks a bunch!